# Pass a function's return object as an argument

Tags: javascript

i am converting an inline event handlers to external js files using addEventListner(). the prefrence

```
onclick="return somefun();"
```

here the some function returns a function. im converting it to

```
elemet.addEventListener("click", somefun)
```

but here somefn() is getting passed instead of the return value of the somefun(). how can i get to pass the return value of the function??

Comment: I guess, but it looked like the answers continued the issue via copy/paste.  Also the way I do this is usually like  - elemet.addEventListener("click", function(event) { somefun();  } );

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `elemet.addEventListener("cilck", function() { somefun(); });` with brackets - ().

This way, the function will execute and the return value will be passed to the event listener.

Comment: its giving error "TypeError: Argument 2 of EventTarget.addEventListener is not an object."

Comment: on totally different case, still your answer gave me a hint to fix my error!